# Multiple Modal Dialogs

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to use multiple modals from this tutorial:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/12/08/inspiration-dialog-effects/

If you scroll down to the comments section you will see that Pedro Botelho posted a solution to this but  his solution isn't working for me and he hasn't replied yet with a solution.

Does anyone see any issues with his solution? When I click the links for bth modals nothing happens.

```
<div class="button-wrap"><button data-dialog="somedialog-1" class="trigger">Open Dialog</button></div>
<div class="button-wrap"><button data-dialog="somedialog-2" class="trigger">Open Dialog</button></div>

<div id="somedialog-1" class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content">
        <h2><strong>Howdy</strong>, I'm a dialog box</h2><div><button class="action" data-dialog-close>Close</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="somedialog-2" class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content">
        <h2><strong>Howdy</strong>, I'm another dialog box</h2><div><button class="action" data-dialog-close>Close</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

(function() {

    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '[data-dialog]' ) ).forEach( function( trigger ) {
        var dlg = new DialogFx( document.getElementById( trigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog' ) ) );

        trigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );
    } );

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try mine. Download from http://bikehappy.org/modal.zip . I'm working to add features. This is what I have so far.

Comment: I forgot to say this has to run from a web server. It uses XMLHttp to pull content and content can't be pulled from a local file system. But you can stuff some text in place of the web request to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks but the client has already approved this modal and I'd like to just resolve the issue with the existing files.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    $('[data-dialog]').each( function(){
        var dlgtrigger = this,
            somedialog = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog' ) ),
            dlg = new DialogFx( somedialog );
        dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );
    });
})();
```